# How to add more divs inside a box div with tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

Here is my problem:

I have a page where I have a box, which has JQuery tabs "Enter" and "About" to change its contents.

EDIT: The full JQuery script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('jquery', '1.4.3');

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            $('#caixa div:not(:first)').hide();

            $('#tabs li').click(function (event) {
                var id = $(event.target).index();
                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(event.target).addClass('active');
                $('#caixa div').hide().eq(id).show();

            });

        }
        );
        </script>
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="active" style="border-top-left-radius: 4px;">Enter</li>
    <li id="2" style="border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-left: 0px;">About</li>
</ul> 
</div>

<div id="caixa">
<div id="enter">
        <p>1</p>
</div>    
<div>
    <p>2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Nothing complicated, but when I try to add more divs inside one, like:

```
    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="active" style="border-top-left-radius: 4px;">Enter</li>
    <li id="2" style="border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-left: 0px;">About</li>
</ul> 
</div>

<div id="caixa">
<div id="enter">
 <div id="login">
        <p>1</p>
 </div>
</div>    
<div>
    <p>2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The text simply doesn't appear, on both tabs.
I know it's probably a problem with my JQuery code, is there someway to make this work?

EDIT: As I stated in the comments I can put both tabs showing different content, what I'm having trouble is having 2 divs inside the "Enter" tab content for example.

Comment: can you please share the fiddle with your code.

Comment: I can't get it to work there but the code is essentially that
http://jsfiddle.net/w7eyr/

Answer (score 0):

from what i could understand from your question...

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3BeM/

```
$('#enter p').wrap("<div id='login'> </div>");
```

you first need to find the selector and wrap your div with new one.

Comment: I'm kinda understanding what you're saying but I have no idea how to apply it to my code haha because the JQuey i have I got it from a video tutorial and I have no knowledge beyond what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so that code you're using is looking for a click on

```
#tabs li
```

Which is nowhere to be found in your html, so I can't image this is doing anything. Can you further explain the problem? You want to click "enter" and have some text displayed and then click "about" and have different text displayed? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to add the list part of the html, i'll edit it soon. i can get the tabs to work you know, enter and about change the content, what i want is like, the content of the tab Enter to have two different divs on it (register and log in) so i can style both of them and have them sepparated easily